# Visual Studio Pro "Could not find part of the path"

Tags: visual-studio

I am at my wits end here. I have checked out a project from our repo and I get this error when building:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\DEV\myproject\BIN\DEBUG'.'
```

This directory exists. I am running VS as an admin. I believe this folder is just recreated when I hit build. I would provide more information if I knew what information to provide.

Where does one begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you check the output window within Visual Studio, do you see any additional information about the build that gives any additional insight about this error? What happens if you delete the BIN folder (including its DEBUG subdirectory) and then rebuild?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Pro are you using?

Comment: I'm trying a Windows refresh real quick... It is 2017

Comment: I don't know why you would do a "Windows refresh", whatever that means. Why not start with what I suggested?

Comment: I already did that once before. No effect this time either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a similar problem - could not build in Release mode, and could not publish.  I fixed it by closing VS, opening the csproj file in Notepad++ (text editor) and deleting the content in `<OutputPath>` for the Release mode.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    **<OutputPath>V:\Programs\Billable_Hours\</OutputPath>**
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then I opened the project in VS and re-set the Release build output path to the bin/Release folder, and everything worked perfectly.